# Using Python To Correlate multiple Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a data frame, which is grouped by two columns "AvailbilityZone" and "InstanceType" as seen below.

[image]

I create this using the following code:

```
#Create full time series and fill data
dfSorted = df.groupby(['AvailabilityZone', 'InstanceType'])
dfSorted = dfSorted.resample('H')
dfSorted = dfSorted.fillna("ffill")
dfSorted = dfSorted.dropna()
```

Every grouping represents a time series. I have already resampled the data so that all the time series are running on an hourly basis. How do I run a correlation to find out how similar each time series is with one another?

When I use:

```
 dfSorted.corr()
```

it just returns SpotPrice = 1 So I am going to assume I will probably have to use something like a loop? and compare each time series with the other? I'm lost any help is much appreciated!

Here Is my dataframe as a csv file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgv8xm5n5o856mx/out.csv?dl=0

I simply used df.tocsv()

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe that we can import using pd.read_clipboard() (or a snippet of code that creates it) as well as the desired/expected output.

Comment: @JulienMarrec I have edited and added a link to my dataframe as csv for download!

Comment: Post df.head() output

Comment: @Boud The image above is exactly that, I used the group by function and that is what is returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main issue you are having is that you are setting up the structure of your data frame incorrectly. What the answer above by burhan has done is restructure your data into lists. What you would need inorder to continue using the `dataframe.corr()` class would be the following structure in your data:

[image: table]

Comment: This is exactly what turned out to be the issue.

Comment: Im glad I was able to pinpoint it late ahaha. Well good luck!

Answer (score 3):

When you create groups, I am assuming you use `groupby`. You can first create your groups:

```
groups = df.groupby(['whatever','grouping'])
```

Then you can get a list of lists for the value you want to correlate, I believe in your case this is `SpotPrice`. So;

```
grouped_prices = [g['SpotPrice'].tolist() for i,g in groups]
```

`numpy.corrcoef` takes list of lists as input then calculates correlation between each list and returns you a correlation coefficient matrix . See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

```
numpy.corrcoef(grouped_prices)
```

This is your correlation coefficient matrix.

`numpy.corrcoef` and `pandas.DataFrame.corr` should give you the same results because by default they both calculate `Pearson` correlation coefficient. I chose to use `numpy.corrcoef` because I think it's easier in this case.

Also, before you use Pearson Correlation you should know that it only measures linear relations between variables and also there are certain assumptions that your data must meet in order to use it. See [here](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/pearsons-product-moment-correlation-using-spss-statistics.php) for example.

Comment: I apologize, didnt realize how much I had left for assumptions I included my code as to how I create the groups. I run into a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2), but your answer is definitely in the right direction will play around and see what I can get.

Comment: Just try to make a list of lists of `SpotPrice` and feed that into `numpy.corrcoef`