# Correlation matrix for multiple time series in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, correlation

Given a `DataFrame` in the form

[image: dataframe]

```
data = [[1, 1, 0.1], [1, 2, 0.3], [1, 3, 0.4], [2, 1, 0.4], [2, 2, 0.5], [2, 3, 1.2]]
dfso = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["timestamp", "item", "value"])
dfso = dfso.set_index("timestamp")
dfso.index = pd.to_datetime(dfso.index)
dfso = dfso.sort_index()
dfso[dfso["item"] == 1]["value"].corr(dfso[dfso["item"] == 2]["value"])
```

It is possible to split the `DataFrame` into separate `Series` and get the correlation between these series individually:

```
df[df['item']==1]['value'].corr(df[df['item']==2]['value'])
```

I would like to group the `DataFrame` by 'item' and create a correlation matrix for the relative correlations between the time series for each item
(the dataset has ~2000 timestamps and 700 items and is complete with no missing or `np.NaN` values)

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1435488 entries, 2023-06-01 00:00:00 to 2023-06-21 23:45:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count    Dtype  
---  ------           --------------    -----  
 0   value            1435488 non-null  float64
 1   item             1435488 non-null  int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 32.9 MB
```

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749080/using-python-to-correlate-multiple-time-series)

but this gives an error:

```
>TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

[`np.corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) will do the work with a suitable [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

Example Data:

```
import pandas as pd

timestamps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
values = [
    [10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
    [12, 18, 9, 30, 36],
    [8, 16, 24, 3, 40],
]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([timestamps, items], names=["timestamp", "item"])
flat_values = [val for sublist in values for val in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame({"value": flat_values}, index=index)
df = df.reset_index().set_index("timestamp")
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

```
import numpy as np

groups = df.groupby(["item"])
grouped_prices = [g["value"].tolist() for i, g in groups]
np.corrcoef(grouped_prices)
```

Output

```
array([[ 1.        , -0.11773393, -0.20875966],
       [-0.11773393,  1.        , -0.75286517],
       [-0.20875966, -0.75286517,  1.        ]])
```